# Good Queuing Theory Introductory Textbook

Tags: reference-request, queueing-theory

I am an undergraduate student who is going to be taking a queuing theory introductory course next semester, I am wondering what's a good introductory book out there? (my math background is probability theory, linear algebra and differential equations)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I thought I'll point you to online resources available for Queueing Theory. Hope this helps!

The [first](http://mathstat.carleton.ca/~zhao/research/QueueingTheory_AdanResing.pdf) one and the [second](http://web2.uwindsor.ca/math/hlynka/qonline.html) one consisting of a list of books available online.

You could also get motivation (at the cost of missing some finer mathematical details) from [here](http://mathstat.carleton.ca/~zhao/research/IntroToQueueingTheory_Cooper.pdf). The solutions are also available [here](http://mathstat.carleton.ca/~zhao/research/QueueingTheory_solns.pdf)

Comment: The first book looks like a good introduction. I'll leave the question open if anyone contributes other resources they know of.

Answer (score 4):

Have you checked out [Leonard Kleinrock's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonard_Kleinrock) books? I am not an expert (in fact, I have taken only an introductory course in queueing theory), and have not read his books; but I wanted to mention them for completeness.

His two-volume book on queueing theory ([*Theory*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471491101) and [*Computer Applications*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/047149111X)) is old now (first published around 1975), so I am guessing they are probably outdated; but I am not sure about this. Also perhaps they are still good enough for an introductory course?

While searching, I also found a problem book [*Queueing Systems: Problems and Solutions*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471555681) that is more recent, but is still 15 years old now. The publishers' note says:

> > Queueing theory is an effective tool for studying several performance parameters of computer systems. It is a difficult subject, and the best way to comprehend queueing theory is by working on information processing problems. This manual contains all of the problems from Kleinrock's *Queueing Systems, Volume 1* and their solutions...

Comment: +1! What were your introductory materials?

Comment: @Tim: I mostly followed my professor's lecture notes, unfortunately I am not allowed to be share it in public. (In fact, I myself lost my personal hard copy. :-)) I am sorry I cannot be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you already got vast knowledge in queuing theory by now. For other novice, my suggestions to start with U. N. Bhat, 2008. It has more chronological details on queuing theory history. Makes a map to reach the theory development knowledge. Another books that can helps in learning queuing models quickly, are  E. P. C. Kao (1996) and Henk C. Tijms (2003).

There are more and latest information at Dr Myron Hlynka's Queueing theory page. 
Hope it can helps the queuing theory learners.